# Update output as user types in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have code to sum four text fields and output the total in a label. Currently the code sums the fields after finishing editing, that is, selecting another text field. Is there a way to sum the text fields as the user types?

```
@IBAction func TankFuelChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    let leftMainTankQuantityValue = Int(leftMainTankQuantity.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let rightMainTankQuantityValue = Int(rightMainTankQuantity.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let auxTankQuantityValue = Int(auxTankQuantity.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let tailTankQuantityValue = Int(tailTankQuantity.text ?? "") ?? 0

    let total = leftMainTankQuantityValue + rightMainTankQuantityValue + auxTankQuantityValue + tailTankQuantityValue

    totalFuelLoad.text = "\(total)"
```

Comment: Hookup your action to the "value changed" event.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, thanks for the response. Sorry for the rookie ignorance, but I am not sure what you mean. Can you explain?

Comment: In your storyboard, connect your action to the "value changed" event of each text field.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, so I go to storyboard, select the first textfield, click connections inspector, click and drag "value changed" to label to total, then select "TankFuelChanged" in the list that pops up?

Comment: You could use [`UITextFieldDelegate#textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield?changes=_9)

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer, thanks for the suggestion. Where do I add that Delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is an event triggered when text field changes. You can drag an action from storyboard or you can add them programmatically by using `addTarget` similar to `UIButton` but need to use event `editingChanged`. Check the following code:

```
var allTextFields: [UITextField] {
    return [leftMainTankQuantity, rightMainTankQuantity, auxTankQuantity, tailTankQuantity]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    allTextFields.forEach { $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTextFieldChange), for: .editingChanged) }
}

@objc private func onTextFieldChange() {
    updateResult()
}

private func updateResult() {
    let strings: [String] = allTextFields.compactMap { $0.text } // Will remove all nil texts
    let integers: [Int] = strings.compactMap { Int($0) } // Will remove all non-integer texts
    let sum = integers.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 }) // Will compute a sum
    print(sum) // TODO: update your result here
}
```

A method must be marked `@objc` because of the `#selector` next to that I hope code speaks for itself.

Comment: Hi @Matic Oblack thank you for that. Works perfectly. I had to change the compactMap to flatMap as I am on 9.2, but other than that, perfect. Thank you so much